# Retrying a failing HTTP request with python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am requesting JSON from an internal API, but occasionally the API gets overloaded and returns `{u'message': u'INTERNAL_ERROR'}`

I would like to continuously retry the request until it succeeds.  What i'm not sure how it do is how to repeat this.  As my code stands now, it will only retry once.

```
r = requests.get(self.time_series_endpoint, params=payload)

json = r.json()

if json.get('message') == 'INTERNAL_ERROR':
    r = requests.get(self.time_series_endpoint, params=payload)
    json = r.json()
    json = json['buckets']
else:
    json = json['buckets']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while json.get('message') == 'INTERNAL_ERROR':
    r = requests.get(self.time_series_endpoint, params=payload)
    json = r.json()
json = json['buckets']
```